# Can anyone suggest me how to use carousel in angular2

Tags: html, angular, carousel

I need to include `angular2-carousel` for the images present in the table. Can anyone help me to do this?

This is the HTML code I tried:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <carousel>
        <img src="http://www.tripathihospital.com/images/hospital.jpg" style="margin:auto;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 style="background-color: transparent;color: white;">Slide {{index + 1}}</h3>
          </div>
       </carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
 </td>
```

Console output:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'carousel' is not a known element:
1. If 'carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Comment: can you show your app module

Comment: @RahulSingh ya i have updated in question

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, have you added hammerJs?

Comment: @Sravan ya i added but it is not sliding

Comment: If you are using `angular-cli` try adding the `carousal` and `hamerjs` scripts in `angular-cli.json`

Comment: @Sravan I am using ng2-bootstrap and is working but not according to my need

Answer (score 0):

[Website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-carousel) states that selector for carousel is not `<carousel>` but is `<carousel-component>`.

Update the selector.

Comment: @Karthik Sharma i used <carousel-component> but didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

It works fine check this [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select) example i created.

I think you are not installing the peer dependencies.

```
npm install @types/hammerjs
npm install hammerjs
```